# Problems with csrftoken in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a bot that logins in at https://rocket-league.com.
I've looked in the form data and saw that i need a 'csrf_token'. So, i tried getting one and passing it in but ran into this error:

```
csrf invalid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    login()
  File "main.py", line 26, in login
    'csrf_token': csrftoken,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'csrftoken' referenced before assignment
```

I've tried different csrf token names without result. However, before this error i got this one allot:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    csrf = c.cookies['csrftoken']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 328, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 399, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

**The code of this error goes like this**

```
username = input(" [?] Email: ")
password = input(" [?] Password: ")
clear()

def login():
    c.get('https://rocket-league.com/functions/login.php')
    if 'csrftoken' in c.cookies:
        csrftoken = c.cookies['csrftoken']
        print(csrftoken)
    else:
        print('csrf invalid')
    
    loginparams = {
        'csrf_token': csrftoken,
        'email': username,
        'password': password,
        'submit': 'Go',
    }
    r = c.post('https://rocket-league.com/functions/login.php', loginparams)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print(Fore.RED + "Login Failed! Restart the program." + Fore.RESET)
    elif r.status_code == 200:
        print(Fore.GREEN+ "Login Succesfull!"+Fore.RESET)

login()
```

Comment: in login function you are using `csrftoken` variable in `loginparams` which will never be defined if condition fails

Answer (score 2):

If there's no csrf cookie you're not giving a value to `csrftoken`, but you're trying to use that variable to initialise `loginparams`. You could change the order like this so variable `csrftoken` is only used if it's valid:

```
def login():
    c.get('https://rocket-league.com/functions/login.php')

    loginparams = {
        'email': username,
        'password': password,
        'submit': 'Go',
    }

    if 'csrftoken' in c.cookies:
        csrftoken = c.cookies['csrftoken']
        loginparams['csrf_token'] = csrftoken
        print(csrftoken)
    else:
        print('csrf invalid')
    
    r = c.post('https://rocket-league.com/functions/login.php', loginparams)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print(Fore.RED + "Login Failed! Restart the program." + Fore.RESET)
    elif r.status_code == 200:
        print(Fore.GREEN+ "Login Succesfull!"+Fore.RESET)
```